# php mysql select all with same data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 3 cols, incremeting id, name, and data

What i'm trying to achieve

you enter a $name... and returns $data...
then
it takes $data and finds all $names that have the same $data.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ='$name' data='$data' and data!='0'
```

does not seem to cut it..

I'm basically trying to get all rows that have the same data as the entered $name's $data.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the following:

```
SELECT  t2.name
FROM    `table` t1
JOIN    `table` t2 ON (t2.data = t1.data)
WHERE   t1.name = '$name' AND t1.data != '0';
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (id int, name varchar(10), data varchar(10));

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1, 'name1', 'data-a');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2, 'name2', 'data-b');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3, 'name3', 'data-a');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (4, 'name4', 'data-b');
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (5, 'name5', 'data-a');
```

Result:

```
SELECT  t2.name
FROM    `table` t1
JOIN    `table` t2 ON (t2.data = t1.data)
WHERE   t1.name = 'name2' AND t1.data != '0';

+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| name2 |
| name4 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The nested query solution [suggested by @Borealid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481485/php-mysql-select-all-with-same-data/3481501#3481501) is another valid solution that returns the same result:

```
SELECT  name 
FROM    `table` 
WHERE   data IN (SELECT data FROM `table` WHERE name = 'name2');

+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| name2 |
| name4 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: none of those seem to work..
may be this could help...

$similar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ='$name'");
//the above code works 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($similar))
{
   echo "<h4>" . $row['name'] . "</h4>";
 echo  "{$row['data']}" ;

but now i want to select all the other name fields that contain the same data as the the name i entered.

// the main problem is it is only returining the data of the name i entered..not the other names with the same data..

//if i confused you.. sorry ..u dont have to answer me.. thanks

Comment: @hann: But is the example I gave what you are looking for?... In my example, the user enters `name2` as `$name`. Now `name2` has `data-b`, which is shared by `name4`, so the query returns `name2` and `name4`. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ='$name' and data='$data' and data!='0'
```

You were missing an `and`

EDIT:

```
select * from table where
 name in 
   ( select data from table where name = '$name' )
```

Comment: Sorry I only corrected your original query but this new edit should work , assuming I understand your question

Answer (score 2):

Try joining the table with itself, if you must do this in one query:

`SELECT * FROM table t1,table t2 WHERE t1.name = '$name' AND t1.data=t2.data AND t1.name != t2.name`

Alternately, use a nested query:

`SELECT name FROM table WHERE data IN (SELECT data FROM table WHERE name='$name')`

I recommend the nested query.  It's easier to read.

What's wrong with your original query as posted is that you're missing an 'AND'.  But it also won't do what you say you want it to.

Comment: You have a small syntax error. The `WHERE` should be after the `LEFT JOIN`. Nevertheless, I don't think this is what the OP is looking for. Your nested query solution is good though :)